# How to get full control styling for data table from DevExtreme React Grid with material-ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, devextreme

I have trouble with styling DevExtreme React Grid, follow by there found from there documentation [here](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/fundamentals/).

Here's the [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-react-grid-for-material-ui-b56kj?fontsize=14) I have from copy some other repo.
My questions:

1. How can I get full control on the styling, because I see `<Table>`component, but is there a way I can adding class to `<th>, <td>`, I would like to add the class or someway to have full control styling for font size, or hover styling.
2. I had a really hard time my table header, like to change to bold and another background color, it's by material UI
3. After I add the [Fixed Columns](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/fixed-columns/) method on scrolling my table, the style is not matching with my other table row, it's changed to all white background, no grey and white on each row
4. When I hit the rest, I would like to row change to be another color.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I checked with their GitHub issues:

Not fully support adding class to the component, but you can [create a theme for it.](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/2108)

About fixColumn styling found the demo from this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-react-grid-for-material-ui-p5xce). Hope this sample help

Pagination issue with sorting can be fixed by this:

```
//after state area:
changePageSize = pageSize => this.setState({ pageSize });
// Plugin
<PagingState
   defaultCurrentPage={0}
   pageSizes={pageSizes}
   defaultPageSize={15}
   onPageSizeChange={this.changePageSize}
/>
<IntegratedPaging />
//UI 
<PagingPanel pageSizes={pageSizes} />
```